# What is the source of this quote about leadership and trust?

Tags: military

What is the source of this quote about leadership and trust? I paraphrase:

> "There are three things a military force has: food, weapons, and trust. A good leader should give up the food and weapons first, and the trust last."

I thought it was Asian, so I looked in Art of War but no luck, and search engine queries with Confucius haven't turned it up either, but my query terms could be off with the paraphrasing.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  I've certainly seen it attributed to Confucius, but then many sayings are attributed to him in the Internet Age. A Google search for `food weapons trust Confucius` seems to give some useful starting points though.

Comment: “*Out of every one hundred men, ten shouldn't even be there, eighty are just targets, nine are the real fighters, and we are lucky to have them, for they make the battle. Ah, but the one, one is a warrior, and he will bring the others back.*” - Heraclitus

Comment: “*The day the soldiers stop bringing you their problems is the day you stopped leading them. They have either lost confidence that you can help them or concluded that you do not care. Either case is a failure of leadership.*” - Colin Powell

Comment: Attributed to [Confucius](https://twitter.com/rachelbotsman/status/922961449982365696?lang=en) [BBC Agrees](https://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/reith2002/lecture1.shtml)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: I recommend posting this as an answer.